# Campo record de Powe BI

Tags: powerbi, sharepoint-online, powerquery

tengo un problemilla con un campo que traigo de una conexión de una lista de SharePoint que... Una vez que importo la tabla de SharePoint... Me guarda el campo como RÉCORD y no hay forma de mostrar la descripción del mismo.

Ese campo record se muestra como un hipervinculo y si accedo a él tiene a su vez más info, title, description, mail etc etc.

Alguien sabe como extraer un dato de este campo record para todas las filas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente debes convertir ese `record` en una tabla. En la imagen puedes ver un caso parecido, aunque es un `list`, el concepto es el mismo. Deberás pulsar sobre el botón "En tabla".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! , nada probé pero no sé si será por la conexión al sharepoint pero no me permite convertirlo asi.
Además creo que así te convertiria en una tabla solo el campo que seleccionas, el problema es que tengo miles de filas...

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione!, aquí en estas flechas! al hacer clic te da la opción de que se cree una columna y muestre el campo que desees!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]